# Remove from ArrayList with String

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I was wondering how is it possible to remove an object from array list using a String. For example I have a class with Students and when I call the remove method I input Name and Last name and the method removes that student from the ArrayList.

I already made a method using exception, but  always get the exception

```
public Student rmv(String name, String lname) throws MyException{
    if(students.contains(new Student(name, lname))){
        students.remove(new Student(name, lname));
    }else{
        throw new MyException("Doesn't exist");
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For this you need to override `equals` method. 
Where in that name and lname fields must be checked.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) 
{

   return firstName.equals(obj.firstName) &&  lastName.equals(obj.lastName);
}
```

If you don't override it then each Student object created using `new` shall be different. And after inserting an element into list, you will never be able to get that ever.

Answer (score 0):

`contains()` checks whether particular object exists in the list through `equals()` method.
So You have to override `equals()` method of `Student` class

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.firstName.equals(obj.firstName) && this.lastName.equals(obj.lastName);
    }
```